# Can a List<T> and its items created and returned to another class during the lifetime of a form survive after its destruction?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a Windows Form A and Windows Form B.

A creates B and shows it as modal (dialog).

User does some job on B and B fires an event which A
listens then closes (DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;)

In the event procedure, a List is returned as 
parameter to listening A and A should use it during its 
lifetime.

The scope of List and its objects it points to are
"private to class B".

My question are:

1. Will `List<x>` survive after disposing (closing) of B?
2. If it will survive, for how long and under what conditions?
   (like until GB is initiated, etc..)
3. When you pass a variable from a control object to another
   control object, how the variable is treated after the destruction
   of the control object it was created?
4. When you pass a variable to another control, shall we get a
   copy to make sure it doesn't fly away with control's destruction?
5. If the pointers which points the object are still in use, 
   will GB still destroy the object after which its scope is lost?

Comment: Can you please add examples for your questions? They are not entirely clear, specially because *pointer* is an uncommon word in c#

Comment: You should test this and find out - it's one of the best ways to learn. Create the situations you describe above and see what happens.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - Uncommon, yes. But technically correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix up the visibility scope of a variable and the lifetime of an object. If there is an active reference to the object, it does survive, even if the original variable is not in scope anymore. It does not matter who created the object or who owns the reference.

For you it means, that if you have a (non-null) reference to an object, the object is always alive; however, if it is a disposable object, its state might not be valid anymore. E.g., when a connection has been disposed (`connection.Dispose();`), the object is still there and its state can be inspected, but the connection became unusable.

The garbage collector (GC) first marks all reachable objects, then it scans the heap to see whether there are non-marked objects, i.e. objects which are not targeted by an active reference anymore, and cleans them up. In reality, the process is more complicated, but you get the general idea.

Here, you can read more on the [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals).

1. Yes.
2. It will survive at least as long as there is one reference to it.
3. If another object has a reference to it, nothing will happen.
4. No.
5. No.

In other words, don't worry. The GC makes its job well and does not destroy the objects you are still using.

Comment: Thank you very much Olivier, it is absolutely clear now.